# Most Efficient Way to Force HTTPS in Nginx in 2020

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I want www and http to redirect to https in Nginx.

There are loads of opinions on how best to do this across the web and the best practices seem to have changed over the years. I've tried a handful of methods all of which seem to work, and that is somewhat concerning to me. I'd like to do it in the most efficient and accepted way. Is there any strong consensus in 2020?

Here's what I'm currently using. Open to any other suggestions as well. I'm using Let's Encrypt for certification and some of the code was automatically added by certbot.

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/mysite/public_html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  access_log off;
  error_page 404 http://example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  }

  location /secret/ {
    internal;
  }

  location /hidden/ {
    internal;
  }

  # A long browser cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 360d;
  }

  # Disable access to dot files LetsEncrypt needs access to well-known
  location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    return 404;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}


server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Having a quick glance at your config it seems you are missing the server_name for the https block.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969930/nginx-generic-redirect-all-www-to-non-www/60970218#60970218).

Comment: Your configuration was partly created by Certbot nginx plugin, and that configuration isn't good.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing HTTPS redirects should follow modern security recommendations.
In 99% cases, you want this to go along with HSTS header implementation.

You probably want to look [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/dissecting-https-redirect-requirements-of-hsts).

With the proper redirect chain, you can securely implement HSTS, which many of the folks miss when applying HTTPS redirects.

Example config for a website with canonical URL including `www.` prefix:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    server_name  example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ... main website directives go here
}
```

Here it is important that when we land on `example.com:80`, we first redirect to its secure version `example.com:443`, and only then to `www.example.com:443`.

This allows the redirect chain to "cover" `example.com` first with the information that the entire domain is meant for secure communication.